# Creating a chart similar to the google analytics funnel

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization

I'd like to create a page which does what the google analytics funnel does, but using data from our own system.

Unfortunately it seems that the funnel isnt exposed in the google charts API, or perhaps it's called something else?  I guess the real value here is not the funnel itself, but all the extra data they put on the page. So; I Wondered if there was some tool that would render all that together?  Or should I just simply create the page from component parts?

Here is a link to a typical funnel:

http://tinyurl.com/4dd8zjy

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Google Analytics !== Google Charts

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Google Analytics Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/mgmtJavascript.html) to make a Goal Feed Request -

> The goal feed provides a quick way to
>   access all the configured goal
>   information for a particular profile.
>   This feed is important because it
>   provides access to goal names, goal
>   types, and goal status (active or
>   inactive). The goal feed is a child of
>   a Profile Feed Entry.

**Goal feed section:**

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/mgmtJavascript.html#goalFeed

Comment: Ok, I just re-read the question. You don't want to use Google Analytics data at all? In that case, you can construct a rudimentary funnel with Google Charts by using bar graphs:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/browse_thread/thread/b5ed391c7d52eabe/13df6a4b2568aac7